# Is there research on how easy patients feel it is to get access to psychiatric medications they want in various countries?

Tags: psychiatry, medication

Regarding availability, satisfaction with diagnosis/ability to receive desired prescription by doctor’s permission, and especially how restrictions in the medical system can lead to long wait times prior to getting access to a medication - comparing that across various countries, and identifying factors at play in those results.